# getChildren(): Return value must be of type Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection, string returned

Tags: php, symfony, entity, arraycollection

In my code, I have implemented OneToMany self-referencing relationship. I have initialized array collection in the constructor. When I send a query parent is added to the children. But when I try to return an object in the children or parent property I get not an Object but an Array collection string. The error looks like this:

> App\Entity\Employee::getChildren(): Return value must be of type
> Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection, string returned

Here is my entity:

```html
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\EmployeeRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=EmployeeRepository::class)
 */
class Employee
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $parent_id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=30)
     */
    private $firstName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=30)
     */
    private $lastName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=40)
     */
    private $position;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=20)
     */
    private $phoneNumber;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $workExperience;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $levelOfKnowledge;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(nullable=true)
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Employee::class, mappedBy="parent")
     */
    private $children;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(nullable=true)
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Employee::class, inversedBy="children")
     */
    private $parent;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->children = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getFirstName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->firstName;
    }

    public function setFirstName(string $firstName): self
    {
        $this->firstName = $firstName;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getLastName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->lastName;
    }

    public function setLastName(string $lastName): self
    {
        $this->lastName = $lastName;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPosition(): ?string
    {
        return $this->position;
    }

    public function setPosition(string $position): self
    {
        $this->position = $position;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPhoneNumber(): ?string
    {
        return $this->phoneNumber;
    }

    public function setPhoneNumber(string $phoneNumber): self
    {
        $this->phoneNumber = $phoneNumber;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail(string $email): self
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getWorkExperience(): ?int
    {
        return $this->workExperience;
    }

    public function setWorkExperience(int $workExperience): self
    {
        $this->workExperience = $workExperience;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getLevelOfKnowledge(): ?int
    {
        return $this->levelOfKnowledge;
    }

    public function setLevelOfKnowledge(int $levelOfKnowledge): self
    {
        $this->levelOfKnowledge = $levelOfKnowledge;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getParent(): ?self
    {
        return $this->parent;
    }
    
    public function setParent(Employee $employee): void
    {
        $this->parent = $employee;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Employee[]|null
     */
    public function getChildren(): Collection
    {
        dump($this->children);
        return $this->children;
    }


    public function __toString(): string
    {
        return $this->children;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getParentId()
    {
        return $this->parent_id;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $parent_id
     */
    public function setParentId($parent_id): void
    {
        $this->parent_id = $parent_id;
    }

}
```

Comment: There seems to be a problem in your __toString method which ***must*** return a string but you are returning `$this->children` which is a Collection. Also your `getChildren` has a return type of Collection but your annotation says Collection or null so your return type should be `?Collection`

Comment: Also, unless there is a very good reason why you are storing parent_id, I would avoid doing so. You should use `$object->getParent()->getId()` to get the parent id and  avoid duplication of data storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in this part:

```
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(nullable=true)
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Employee::class, mappedBy="parent")
     */
    private $children;
```

as you've mapped your field both as a column and a relation. You must not use `@Column` along with `@OneToMany` as it's not even making sens - the `children` is not reflected in the database anyway.